# Autorunning CSS-change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are solutions out there to solve that; but I want to get this done on my "own" (you got to know your limitations: Hello stackoverflow) path. So I want a sort of carousel, where the whole ul-element gets a negative margin-left per a set time-interval as long as the user doesn't hover the ul-area. So it's initially something like that:

```
var index_versatz = -100;
var index_position = 0;
var index_position_vw = 0;

 $(document).ready(function () {
    index_position += index_versatz;
    index_position_vw = index_position + "vw";
    $(".content__index ul").delay(1200)
        .queue(function (next) {
            $(this).css('margin-left', index_position_vw);
            next();
        });
});
```

with a html-structure like that:

```
 <ul>
            <!-- Slide -->
            <li class="index_start">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <h2>Text</h2>
</li>
            <!-- Slide -->
            <li class="index_lagen">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <h2>Text</h2>
</li>
            <!-- Slide -->
            <li class="index_optimist">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <h2>Text</h2>
</li>
            <!-- Slide -->
            <li class="index_funktion">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <h2>Text</h2>
</li>
        </ul>
```

And for me as a very first step that works, but it just does those changes to the very first slide while I want it to run automatically, as long as nobody hovers the `.content__index ul` - area.

I'll need to do 2 things there:
- Use a different handler (?) then .ready (or tell the script to start again)
- and an if-expression to detect if the user hovers the area.

You would really already help me a lot with the very first block on how to run that whole thing automatically.

Comment: Why do you need a different handler than `ready`? Also, what's the hovering action for?

Comment: I don't need a different handler then ready, but I need something to make that code load automatically from the start. With the current version it is just running once.

Comment: The hovering is to detect if someone hovers the area, and if so, make the movement pause

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question? _"With the current version it is just running once"_  There appears to only be one item in queue? Not certain what issue is?

Comment: Are you trying to perform a slideshow with `<li>` elements?

Comment: @guest271314 exactly

Comment: @Daiaiai _"as long as nobody hovers the"_ What should occur if `<ul>` is hovered over?

Comment: the slideshow should pause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.clearQueue()` to empty the queue array at `.hover()`, `.stop()` to stop animation at `li` element, `.slice()` to reset the queue from current index of functions in queue array; `.promise()`, `.then()` to perform task when all animations completed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ul = $("ul").data("index", 0)
  , li = $("li", ul)
    // set duration
  , d = 1200
    // create `q` array of functions to call
    // in sequential order, where `el` is current `li` element
  , q = $.map(li, function(el, index) {
          return function(next) {
            // set `ul` `data-index` to current `li` index:`q` function index 
            ul.data("index", index)
            // do stuff, call next function in `q` queue
            .find(el).fadeIn(d).delay(d).fadeOut(d, next);
          }
        });
  ul.hover(
    // handle at `ul` `mouseenter` event
    function() {
    // clear `ul` queue; clear, stop `li` animation queue
    ul.clearQueue("_fx").find(li).stop(true);
  }
    // handle at `ul` `mouseleave` event
  , function() {
      // reset `ul` queue at current `li` using `index`
      // set at last function called in queue
      ul.queue("_fx", q.slice(ul.data().index)).dequeue("_fx");
  })
  .delay(d, "_fx").queue("_fx", q).dequeue("_fx").promise("_fx")
  .then(function() {
    // do stuff when `ul` queue completes   
    $(this).hide(function(){
      alert("slideshow complete");
    })
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
ul:hover {
  cursor: wait;
  border: 2px solid sienna;
}
ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <!-- Slide -->
  <li class="index_start">
    <h1>Text 1</h1>
    <h2>Text 1</h2>
  </li>
  <!-- Slide -->
  <li class="index_lagen">
    <h1>Text 2</h1>
    <h2>Text 2</h2>
  </li>
  <!-- Slide -->
  <li class="index_optimist">
    <h1>Text 3</h1>
    <h2>Text 3</h2>
  </li>
  <!-- Slide -->
  <li class="index_funktion">
    <h1>Text 4</h1>
    <h2>Text 4</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/U74oTZz1G4Xu7miFmcuK?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to put this in a function, set a global variable that you will set with `setTimeout(function(){yourFunctionName();}, givenTime)` at the end of your function.

That way your function is called at regular interval, and you can call a `clearTimeout(yourTimeoutGlobalVariable);` on event hover.

PS: I didn't wrote the whole script so you can do it your "own way", tell me if you're still stuck.