# jQuery:Pause image sliding on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want image slider pause on hover. 
This my code

```
 $(".col-md-8").hover(function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            });
```

It seems to me correct, but something goes wrong. What is an issue? Thanks in advance.

[Link to my project in Codepen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/xOPyZR)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334119/autorunning-css-change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this **[Pen](http://codepen.io/cheralathan/pen/BzJvoa)**

```
var nextimage = 0;
var timer = 0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow() {
  if (nextimage >= images.length) {
    nextimage = 0;
  }
  $('.col-md-8').css('background-image', 'url("' + images[nextimage++] + '")').fadeIn(3000, function() {
    timer = setTimeout(doSlideshow, 3000);
  });
}
$(".col-md-8").hover(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});

$(".col-md-8").mouseout(function() {
  setTimeout(doSlideshow, 3000);
});

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-8");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
 elems[i].style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
 elems[i].style.backgroundSize = "100%";
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. BTW why did you create timer and assigned to zero?

Comment: you assigned timer = setTimeout(doSlideshow, 3000); it always return 1. If you set it to 0 it will return the timer value exactly. Then we can able to clear timer